# Cannot start Apache on Ubuntu 22.04 running PHP 8.1.2. How to install missing PHP load module?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php

I am on Ubuntu 22.04. I recently upgraded PHP from 7.4 to 8.1

**PHP version:**

```
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 (cli) (built: Nov  2 2022 13:35:25) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

**Apache version:**

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2022-06-14T12:30:21
```

When running the following command,

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

I am getting this:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xeu apache2.service" for details.
```

Running `apachectl configtest` gives me the following:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.4.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

I looked inside `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` folder, but there is no module for PHP 8.1. I can only see `php7.4.load`.

What is the correct way to resolve this problem? Looks like I am missing the module, but don't know how to install it and go ahead with further configuration.

Please suggest!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/629995/apache-not-able-to-restart good luck!!! have a nice day!!!